# ListView footer elements are not clickable after the filling the header textboxes

Tags: android, listview, button, header, footer

I have `ScrollView` header of the listView with a lot of elements. And footer with 2 buttons. And when I fill the headers elements, and push footer's button, it is not firing. And when I click on the header's item

```
    btnSubmitOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View view) {
           header.clearFocus();
           btnSubmitOrder.setFocusable(true);
           Log.i("new order button","fires");

    }
 });
```

the text of the Log item shows in the LogCat the same times as I pushed it. So why does this happen? How can I make footer's button react immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved issue by using

```
btnSubmitOrder.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        {
                     header.clearFocus();
                        }
                   }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

add android:onClick="onYourClick" and android:clickable="true" to your footer xml

in your ListActivity add function:

```
 public void onYourClick(View v){
     header.clearFocus();
     btnSubmitOrder.setFocusable(true);
     Log.i("new order button","fires");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be that the listview and footerview are fighting for focus try this:

```
 mylistView.addFooterView(footerView, null, false);
```

where false tells the footer its not selectable.  I tested this myself and the buttons inside the footer respond to touches now.  I hope this an acceptable answer.

otherwise you'll have to use a ontouchlistener as you mentioned as the listview and button are fighting for focus and listview is winning.